# Detect Browser zoom level using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to detect the browser zoom level when the user changed the zoom level of browser, and the default zoom level using javascript. I need to call different xml files according to the zoom level change.

Comment: -1: Don't repost the same question just because you don't like the original answer.

Comment: Especially when the original answer was perfectly valid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Answer (score 6):

I found that you have to vary for each browser:

This works great in safari and chrome:

```
zoom = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, null).width,10)/document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

This works well in IE8+ (unless your user has some freakish screen....):

```
zoom = window.screen.deviceXDPI/96
```

And for Firefox and IE7 I use [this](http://blog.sebastian-martens.de/2009/12/how-to-detect-the-browser-zoom-level-change-browser-zoo/)
although I still haven't got it to work with Firefox on the Mac...

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the current zoom ratio relative to the initial zoom when the page was first loaded , if it was loaded with no zoom ( 100% ) then it will give you the real actual current zoom :

```
window.addEventListener('resize',()=>{
    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
      html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
      const ratio = ( height /  document.documentElement.clientHeight )
      if (!window.zc_)
      {
        window.zc_ = 100/ratio
      }
    const zoom = ratio* window.zc_
    console.log(
      zoom
      );
    })
```